# Select the first records for a property with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select

I have a class

```
class Test
{
    public string FirstProp { get; set; }
    public string SecondProp { get; set; }
    public string ThirdProp { get; set; }
}
```

and a list of objects

```
var list = new List<Test>
{
    new Test { FirstProp = "xxx", SecondProp = "x2", ThirdProp = "x3" },
    new Test { FirstProp = "xxx", SecondProp = "x21", ThirdProp = "x31" },
    new Test { FirstProp = "yyy", SecondProp = "y2", ThirdProp = "y3" },
    new Test { FirstProp = "yyy", SecondProp = "y21", ThirdProp = "y31" },
    new Test { FirstProp = "xxx", SecondProp = "x22", ThirdProp = "x32" },
};
```

I need to select the first FirstProp records:

```
FirstProp = "xxx", SecondProp = "x2", ThirdProp = "x3"
FirstProp = "yyy", SecondProp = "y2", ThirdProp = "y3"
```

How to do it in the best way using `linq`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: You said you want to select "FirstProp" and you are selecting "FirstProp = "xxx", SecondProp = "x2", ThirdProp = "x3"" ?

Comment: I need only first record for FirstProp=="xxx", first for "yyy", first for "someother" etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) on the property `FirstProp`, and then do get `First`:

```
 list.GroupBy(x => x.FirstProp).Select(g => g.First())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list.GroupBy (l => l.FirstProp).Select (l => l.First ())
```

will work here but you need to determine what item from each group you need to take (First is not always a good choice)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Distinct` property

```
var result = list.DistinctBy(t => t.FirstProp);
```

Comment: `DistinctBy` is not a part of standard linq, it's an extension from the [morelinq project](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

Comment: Oh okay then. Then I guess Group By is idd the way to go